# Repeating and spaces

Tags: c++

So, I have a small text-based game going, and my most of my stuff is set up okay, but it resets if a keyword is incorrect, and you have to search the first keyword again to continue along the path thread. Also, I added sleep at the last of the if statements, to further ask how I could apply the delayed typing effect on cout statements. If it's not possible, thanks anyways. Let me know, I'd love some input, and would like to be unstuck, here.

````
char intro[] = "INTRO_TEXT";

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(intro); i++) {
cout << intro[i];
Sleep(30);
}

char result00[] = "RESULT_TEXT00";
char result01[] = "RESULT_TEXT01";
char result02[] = "RESULT_TEXT02";

int i = 1;
while (i < 5) {

string path00;
cin >> path00;

if (path00 == "example1") {
cout << result00 << endl;

string path01;
cin >> path01;

if (path01 == "example2") {
cout << result01 << endl;

string path02;
cin >> path02;

if (path02 == "example3) {
cout << result02 << endl;
Sleep(30);
}

else {
cout << "Not a keyword." << endl;
int i = 0;
      }
   }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to structure how you store your game world differently. A tree might be a good choice so that you could simply store a reference to where you are in the tree.

Here's a sample implementation that lets the user walk back and forth between different "rooms", and does not lose its place if the action is unknown:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Room {
    std::map<std::string, Room*> actions;
    std::string description;
};

Room *buildRooms() {
    Room *startingRoom = new Room();
    startingRoom->description = "You are in a dimly lit room. You see doors to the north and south";

    Room *northRoom = new Room();
    northRoom->description = "You are in a closet. There is a door to the south";
    northRoom->actions["south"] = startingRoom;
    startingRoom->actions["north"] = northRoom;

    Room *southRoom = new Room();
    southRoom->description = "You are in a field. There is a building with a door to the north.";
    southRoom->actions["north"] = startingRoom;
    startingRoom->actions["south"] = southRoom;

    return startingRoom;
}

void playGame() {
    Room *currentRoom = buildRooms();

    while(currentRoom != nullptr) {
        std::cout << currentRoom->description << std::endl;

        std::string userInput;
        std::cin >> userInput;

        Room *nextRoom = currentRoom->actions[userInput];

        if(nextRoom == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Not a keyword" << std::endl;
        } else {
            currentRoom = nextRoom;
        }
    }
}
```

The important difference is that where you are (the pointer to currentRoom) is stored outside of your game loop.

For the delayed printing effect you could write a function that takes a string and prints it out with a delay between characters, then use that in place of std::cout everywhere that you want that text effect.

For example:

```
void say(std::string text) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        std::cout << text.at(i);
        Sleep(30);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this; it's helped me figure out a restructure of my game.

Comment: So, I used the struct that's written just like this one, but how do I get the ``description`` to print with a delay? Or, is there a way to turn it into a ``char`` statement?

Comment: Well, if you want to access description as a standard char array you would call room->description.c_str(). Alternatively you could use a function like I provided at the end of my answer, which you would then call like so: say(room->description).